# How should I repair this damaged appliance cord?

Tags: wiring, repair, appliances

I have the electrical cord on a device that operates in a generally damp and potentially wet environment.  It's been nicked with a knife and some of the copper is exposed.  What's my best option to repair it?  Is electrical tape enough?

[image]

Comment: Can this cable be easily replaced? What appliance does it connect?

Comment: The cable cannot be easily replaced.  It is an aquarium air pump.

Comment: Those airpumps can be taken apart to replace the cable - what is your issue? missing tools?

Comment: What voltage?..

Comment: If you shortened the cord and put a new plug on, would that work?

Comment: @jay613 Voltage isn't the correct unit of measure for cable thickness. We need to know what Amperage or Wattage?

Comment: @Nelson with damaged insulation the voltage is the main consideration and here, what I meant (and should have asked) is whether it's 120V or 12V (or other low voltage).  The answer to the question would be different accordingly.

Comment: @jay613 low voltage AC is practically non-existent, so you're really asking whether this cable is before a power brick or after. Anything before is full residential AC power and very dangerous, and anything after is normally DC and relatively safer unless it is a super weird device that has DC of over 100v. But cable size alone relative to the finger in the picture, even if it is a pinky, clearly puts it out of low voltage DC level.

Comment: @Nelson  There are quite a few low voltage AC applications around the house. most low voltage outdoor landscape lights are 12VAC, many LED lights for outdoor lighting can run on AC,  most thermostat circuits and contactors run on 24VAC and most door bell circuits are 16 to 24VAC just to name a few.  I also have a few wall warts that have AC output.

Comment: This should probably be on a GFCI even without the damaged cord, due to the guaranteed presence of water.

Comment: 1) Cut it and put a cord-end there. 2) Tape it, because you don't care and don't have kids. 3.a) Open the device and put an entire new cord, or 3.b) put what's left of your cutoff that still has an end on it.

Comment: *appliance* : "The appliances and equipment category includes larger devices that are plugged into **electricity mains [line voltage]**" https://www.iea.org/energy-system/buildings/appliances-and-equipment - Y'all are talking about *consumer products*; low voltage or not: i.e., a Sonos. A DW is an *appliance*. The furnace et al are *equipment*.

Answer (score 12):

Electrical tape by itself is not enough.

The best option is to replace the cord or the tool.

If you can't replace the cord or tool, the next-best option is to use glue lined heat shrink tubing or some other waterproof seal. You will need probably to remove the cord from the tool to do that.

If that's not an option, you can use electrical tape, *provided you always use the tool on a GFCI outlet or with a GFCI extension cord*. It's not generally safe, because if the tool is ever used without a GFCI in a damp environment it will be dangerous.

Comment: And if you remove the cord, you can replace it, rather than putting heat shrink on it.

Comment: Glue lined heat shrink tubing is the best bet. To apply that, one could cut the plug, apply the tubing and add an repair plug

Comment: I've noticed that heat shrink tubing is not a good repair option for cables that need to flex. The shrinking process hardens it, and the tubing ends up being failure points because it cuts into the existing insulation as you flex the cable.

Comment: It depends on the brand. I have some that is super flexible, and some that becomes very stiff once hardened. Either way I'd aim to use a relatively short piece, maybe five times the length of the damage.

Comment: @Martin good though, I hadn't considered a repair plug. I still put the options in this order. I'd include the tape listed in the other answer as a last tier option, because my experience has been that it only lasts for a while in cord duty, which is why they require an overwrap.

Comment: "Electrical tape by itself is not enough" --- why?

Comment: @Matthias OP says the environment is damp and potentially wet. I don't think electrical tape makes reliable seals against water and moisture.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a standard self-fusing electrical tape to insulate and waterproof the damaged area, then overwrap that with standard vinyl electrical tape.

Sample self-fusing tape:

[image]

Installation instructions:

[image]

Comment: Note that the instructions quoted say that tape is intended for low voltage applications. It is UL listed up to 600V, but that's for the tape, not for the seal. It might work in this application, it might not. It would at least be an improvement over leaving wire exposed.

Comment: @keshlam, the EU Low Voltage Directive (LVD) applies to equipment designed to work with up to 1000V AC or 1500V DC. Normal mains voltage is considered to be low voltage here.

Comment: Check which meaning 3M intended, since it seems either is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the concerns that I know of:

1. Risk of shock.
2. Risk of the copper deteriorating.
3. Narrowed conductor

## Shock

There is always a risk of shock with exposed copper — especially if the exposed conductor is positive, but also if neutral or even ground, because who knows, the outlet receptacle may be wrongly installed with reverse polarity, and the ground may be defective.

The point is: fix the insulation.

## Copper degradation

The metal may oxidize when exposed to water or salt or even airborne particles. Copper and aluminum may oxidize and eventually fall apart. This may cause arcing and heat — a fire hazard.

## Narrowed conductor

Electrical wires need to have a certain thickness so they can carry their rated current without overheating. If you narrow a part of the wire by cutting into it, that part of the wire may get hotter than usual. I don't know *by how much*, but it's a factor.

If the copper is *stranded* (instead of solid), then if you cut through a strand, the degradation can get worse over time. At first only the cut will be the narrowed portion of the wire. The rest of the strand will still be in copper-to-copper contact with the other copper strands, and conducting. But, if corrosion enters the wire, the strands will corrode so that the copper of the cut strand is no longer touching the other strands, so it cannot conduct between strands. And eventually this will happen along the whole length of the wire, meaning the whole wire will be narrowed by one strand.

## Fixes

### Electrical tape

Electrical tape can prevent both corrosion and shock, but only if applied properly. It does not fix the conductor narrowing though.

Electrical tape should be wrapped without wrinkles or gaps, and cover the cut and a generous section before and after it.

The problem with your wire is that it's not a solid round cord; it's two cords joined together. The center valley will not be sealed. You have to separate the cord along the valley, to wrap only the cut cord. Then it will seal because you're wrapping a round cord. Once the bad side is wrapped, you can join the two cords again with tape for the sake of appearance.

Maybe someone can comment about *which type* of electrical tape to use.

### Dielectric grease

To further prevent against corrosion, consider applying dielectric grease (e.g. silicone) into the cut, to keep water away from the copper.